# How to use a variable within script task when variable is defined via browser UI "Run pipeline"

Tags: azure-pipelines

I want to define a variable in the browser UI before an Azure pipeline is being triggered.
The value of this variable shall be reused in a "script" task as part of a condition.

Using the runtime expression style ${{ variables.variablename }} in an if condition did lead to an empty string.

Also looking at different documents I do not find the right explanation for how to use it. I also have the feeling that variables defined in the browser UI are different variables than the ones defined in the pipeline yml file.

I have seen one example pipeline in the past where the variable was used in a script task using this syntax: $(varName). Does it mean every variable is automatically provided as a script variable to every script task?

Can you please help in understanding this variable usage scenario?

Thank you

Comment: Found the doc page now that explains it to me, finally. In case somebody has the same issue here is the page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#understand-variable-syntax

Comment: And regarding my above questions: Every variable seems to be made available as an env variable. And the reasong why the runtime expression likely did not work out and instead the macro expression was required $(var) is that the runtime expression must cover the whole row in the pipeline: "The runtime expression must take up the entire right side of a key-value pair."